# Приведение типов в Java через Reflection

Tags: java, рефлексия

Можно ли как-то привести один тип к другому, не создавая кучу ifов? Тип заранее не знаю, так как получаю его через Reflection.

К примеру, если я передаю Int , а в параметрах метода стоит Float, можно ли как-то привести одно к другому?

```java
    String param = availibleMethods.get(m.getName());
    Object value = null;
    if(param != null)
        value = attachment.arguments.get(param);
    
    if(value == null)
        return;
    
    Parameter[] parameters = m.getParameters();
    
    if(parameters.length != 1)
            return;
    
    Class type = parameters[0].getType();
        
    m.invoke(obj , value);
```

Пишу ботов для Telegram, нужно передавать вложения, а в [Java Telegram API](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api) для этого создано 10 классов с, по сути, одинаковыми методами. Хочу сделать единый обработчик для этого не городя огромную кучу ifов.

Comment: Приведите пример кода и объясните подробнее, что вы делаете и зачем.

Comment: Похоже, что вы используете не тот язык программирования, о чём сигнализирует попытка использования рефлексии для обхода статической типизации.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , а что Вы посоветуете вместо использования 10 разных классов?)

Comment: @НикитаСергеевичБольшаков, что такое `API java` и `10 классов`, пробовали использовать SDK (библиотечки)?

Comment: @BigTows , ошибочка, Java Telegram bot API)

Comment: @НикитаСергеевичБольшаков вот [это](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api)?

Comment: @BigTows , да, этот. Там везде классы( SendPhoto , SendAudio , SendVoice и т.д ) и все с похожими сеттерами

Comment: @НикитаСергеевичБольшаков посоветую _фабрику_.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать 10 классов с одинаковыми методами, но разной реализацией, то вам не рефлексия нужна, а [абстракция](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1981-dlja-chego-v-java-nuzhnih-interfeysih).

Условно есть интерфейс

```
interface SomeInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

И есть классы:

```
class A implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}

class B implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

и т.д.

Тогда в коде вы можете работать с ними не как с отдельными классами, а как с объектом *SomeInterface*

```
SomeInterface a = new A();
SomeInterface b = new B();
```

Вы так же можете создавать из них списки. И вызывать метод `doSomething()`, а вот реализация этого метода может быть везде разная.

Comment: Если бы они наследовались, я бы так и сделал, но они называются одинаково, но при этом не наследуются от какого-либо интерфейса, в котором есть эти методы. То есть в каждом из классов есть, к примеру, метод setChatId, но при этом я не могу их вызывать одинаково, просто сделав так: SomeInterface a = new ConcreteClass(); А потом a.setChatId();